# Powerline-status & iTerm2 3.0 glyphs not rendering

Tags: macos, terminal, fonts

Ever since I upgraded to iTerm2 3.0 (currently 3.0.2) the Powerline fonts aren’t rendering with the special glyphs in the Terminal. The glyphs still render in VIM, so I know they’re there.

I’m guessing that something about this update is preventing Powerline shell from detecting the fonts so it falls back to standard glyphs.

Is there something I can do to force Powerline shell to use its special glyphs regardless of what the probe finds?

Wrong glyphs in iTerm2 shell:

[image: Wrong glyphs]

Right glyphs in iTerm2 VIM:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have fixed itself with a few reboots.  Very strange.